# Qt unresolved external symbol after refactoring

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I had a properly working Qt code with custom widget. Then I refractored a signal name and undo the action immediately. Since then I'm getting -

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void
__thiscall QWidget::mouseDoubleClicked(class QMouseEvent *)"
?mouseDoubleClicked@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
```

mouseDoubleClicked is the method which wmits the refractored signal. Although I undo the refractoring action but still it's giving this error. The same code did run bofe that.

I've tried cleaning and running qMake but no success. Even created a new project and copy pasted the file contents but still got the same error.

These are the files-

mainwindow.h

```
#pragma once;


#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

myqtimagewidget.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QWidget>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QtGui/QMouseEvent>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

class MyQtImageWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    QImage qimage;
    cv::Mat temp;

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);
    void mouseDoubleClicked(QMouseEvent* event);
   // void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

public:
    explicit MyQtImageWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {}
    QSize sizeHint() const {return qimage.size(); }
    QSize minimumSizeHint() const {return qimage.size(); }


signals:
    void signalMouseMoved(QString);

public slots:
    void showImage(const cv::Mat &image);

};
```

myqtimagewidget.cpp

```
#include "myqtimagewidget.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

void MyQtImageWidget::showImage(const Mat &image)
{
    //resize image to fit widget. Maintains aspect ratio

    int width = this->maximumWidth();
    int hight = this->maximumHeight();

    Mat rescaledImg;

    if(image.cols > width || image.rows > hight)
    {
        // debug info --v
        QString data = "Original dimention: " + QString::number(image.cols) + "x" + QString::number(image.rows);
        qDebug(data.toStdString().c_str());
        // debug info --^

        double aspectRatio = (double)image.cols / (double)image.rows; // width / height
        cv::Size2i newSize;

        // debug info --v
        qDebug(std::to_string(width).c_str());
        qDebug(std::to_string(hight).c_str());
        // debug info --^

        if(image.cols >= image.rows)
        {
            newSize = cv::Size(width, width / aspectRatio);
        }
        else
        {
            newSize = cv::Size(hight * aspectRatio, hight);
        }

        cv::resize(image, rescaledImg, newSize, 1, 1);

        // debug info --v
        data = "Resized dimention: " + QString::number(rescaledImg.cols) + "x" + QString::number(rescaledImg.rows);
        qDebug(data.toStdString().c_str());
        // debug info --^
    }
    else
        rescaledImg = image;

    // Convert the image to the RGB888 format
    switch (rescaledImg.type())
    {
        case CV_8UC1:
                cvtColor(rescaledImg, temp, CV_GRAY2RGB);
                break;
        case CV_8UC3:
                cvtColor(rescaledImg, temp, CV_BGR2RGB);
                break;
    }

    // QImage needs the data to be stored continuously in memory
    assert(temp.isContinuous());
    // Assign OpenCV's image buffer to the QImage. Note that the bytesPerLine parameter
    // (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-6) is 3*width because each pixel
    // has three bytes.
    qimage = QImage(temp.data, temp.cols, temp.rows, temp.cols*3, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    repaint();
}

void MyQtImageWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    // Display the image
    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawImage(QPoint(0,0), qimage);
    painter.end();
}

void MyQtImageWidget::mouseDoubleClicked(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    int x = event->pos().x(), y = event->pos().y();

    QString data = "x: " + QString::number(x) + ", y: " + QString::number(y);

    emit MyQtImageWidget::signalMouseMoved(data);
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "myqtimagewidget.h"

using namespace cv;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString imageSrc = "E:\\Images\\Panorama\\Harshil3578_stitch.jpg";
    Mat image = imread(imageSrc.toStdString(), IMREAD_COLOR);



}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

In the GUI I have a widget promoted to `MyQtImageWidget` and connected to a QLabel.

Comment: clean the project and rebuild, it's likely that myqtimagewidget.cpp wasn't recompiled

Comment: @ratchetfreak, I've already tries that. If I build each file individually then they they get built but the whole project gives the error when building.

Comment: One very very strange thing is that the same error appears even in every Qt GUI project , even a fresh GUI project with no added files adn UI elements. Does this have to do something `promoted widgets`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider what the linker is telling you:

- QWidget has a virtual method named mouseDoubleClicked.
- That method is not implemented.

The problem is that QWidget does *not* have a virtual method named mouseDoubleClicked.  My best guess is that during your refactoring, you somehow modified the header file for QWidget, renaming an existing virtual function to mouseDoubleClicked.

If that's the case, getting a fresh copy of qwidget.h (or re-installing Qt) should resolve the problem.

Comment: I did try reinstalling Qt but the same problem in every GUI project. Then I created a new project and copied the code form old project except the mouse handelling method. It built nad ran. Then I reimplemented QWidget's `mouseDoubleClickEvent` and got the same error. Then I removed it and reimplemented the `mousePressEvent` (it worked successfully) and renamed it back to 'mouseDoubleClickEvent' and things started working correctly. I also changed the class name of custom widget. Strange things happening.